# Searching (fast!) VNC client for Windows with Bonjour detection

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing, bonjour

I tried `ScreenRecycler` for my Macbook and accessed it successfully with VNC via my second Laptop (as connected to the same WLAN) and it works if i enter the IP address of the MB. However, i am searching for a VNC client which offers my the ability to find the MB via Bonjour because i want to run the viewer on my Windows PC (i have Ubuntu too if this will work better!) which is connected via LAN and therefore it can't find the laptop, neither with a `ping`.
Furthermore, RealVNC seems to be painfully slow and therefore i want to know whether there is any faster client. My research had the result that there exists `JollyFastVNC` which is only available for Mac and therefore does neither support Windows nor Ubuntu...

Comment: I think this question should be moved as you seem to be looking for a VNC viewer for Windows

Comment: @macaco: Searching a VNC client with Bonjour-capability (if it workes under my circumstances) is indeed Apple-related and i think the best place to ask the question would be here... or do you suggest any other part of stackexchange?

Comment: bonjour is just name resolution. If you can't even ping the MB by IP, bonjour won't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your LAN and WLAN (assuming that you mean Wireless LAN and **not** WAN) networks are isolated from one another, that's a bigger problem that you're gonna have to resolve before you go looking for a VNC client. You're not gonna be able to VNC between the machines regardless of what client you use.

Comment: Can you tell me what reasons might prevent the computers from their detection? I am not into networking and therefore do not know how to solve this issue! (And yes, it is WLAN.)

Comment: That's a very separate question and you should maybe ask it over at SuperUser after doing some research based on the network equipment you are using.

Answer (score 1):

[Remotix](http://nulana.com/remotix-windows/) sounds like what you're looking for.  It does VNC, RDP, and supports SSH tunnels (nice for remoting in via an SSH jumpbox!)

Answer (score 0):

[Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) doesn't user Bonjour, but you can add computers to a kind of contact list and connect to them with one click. Works over the internet as well.

Comment: I am not searching for a remote access client. ScreenRecycler offers me the ability to use multiple monitors via VNC - thats why i want to be able to use my Windows PC with my huge monitor. Teamviewer is not what i am searching for!